# Generosity in the World Happiness Score

Tags: society, indicators

One factor in the [World Happiness Score](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/World_Happiness_Report#/2018_report) is [generosity](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Generosity). I have trouble understanding, what this actually means and how it enters into the score.

These are my specific questions:

1. Does "generosity" mean that the individuals **feel** or **are** generous themselves (which feels good)?
2. Does it mean that the individuals **experience** generosity by their fellow citizens (which would affect happiness in a different way)?
3. Does it mean that the individuals experience generosity by their government or employer or other superior party?
4. Does it mean **all of this together**, giving a cumulated number of some kind?
5. Why is generosity preferred to other similar factors like **fairness** or **solidarity**?

Comment: Terminology in this area doesn't have very clear defintions https://generosityresearch.nd.edu/assets/11794/social_psycho/social_psychology_of_generosity.pdf So asking why one term and not another as a label for one operational definition is a bit opinion-based. (It would also have been a better question on psychology.SE.)

Comment: @Fizz: I'll take your advice.

Comment: @Fizz: https://psychology.stackexchange.com/questions/23215/generosity-in-the-world-happiness-score

Answer (score 4):

According to [Changing World Happiness](https://worldhappiness.report/ed/2019/changing-world-happiness/):

> Generosity is the residual of regressing the national average of [Gallup World Poll] responses to the question “Have you donated money to a charity in the past month?” on GDP per capita.

Comment: Which sense does this question make in very poor countries resp. for very poor people? It can be asked sensibly only to somewhat wealthy people (who have enough to give something away).

Comment: Furthermore: In the Western world people donate money mainly around Christmas, so this question should be asked with respect to the past year. (And the answer should be interpreted with reservation: Does donating once a year at Christmas a rather small amount of money really reflect "generosity"?)

Comment: @Hans-PeterStricker I don't think it's correct to assume that only 'wealthy' people can be generous. It's possible to be generous with other things besides just money, for example time or property. For example, a (relatively) poor villager in Bangladesh might be generous by spending some time helping their neighbor rebuild their house after a hurricane, or sharing some food with them. Conversely, there are many very wealthy people who are not at all generous. I don't think generosity necessarily correlates with wealth.

Comment: You are absolutely right, but the WHR question asks for an amount of money.

Comment: And it asks not even for a specific amount of money (e.g. related to the available amount of money). So how can it provide a good measure of generosity?

Comment: @Hans-PeterStricker: it's not the only measure of generosity conceivable. But it uses the widely available Gallup data (on which the [WGI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_Giving_Index) is also based, albeit the latter uses three mostly qualitative questions.) The WHS version tries to make it sensitive to how rich/poor the country is (hence regression to GDP per capita, which WGI doesn't do.)

Comment: @Hans-PeterStricker: measures of gross sacrifice have also been used/proposed e.g. https://philanthropy.iupui.edu/doc/academics/philanthropy-research-workshop/prw160920.pdf it's just that it's harder to get such data worldwide.